# Passwords differ for TTY and KDE

Tags: kubuntu, password

I am rather a Linux beginner, so pardon me if I get my terms mixed up a bit. I am running Kubuntu and had a password (let's call it `A`) for my account (`acc`). I wanted to change it, so I ran TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F6), logged as `acc` with password `A`, ran `$ passwd` and changed it to password `B`.

Now, I can log into TTY as `acc` with password `B`, but cannot log in the KDE (~the graphic desktop) with neither `A` nor `B`. I tried changing it through System Settings, but that does not work, since I need to provide my current password (which should be `B`, but for some reason is not).

What did happen? How can I reset the password? I tried changing it to password `C`, but to no good.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why my approach didn't work, but logging as root and deleting my password `$ passwd -d acc` did the trick. Weird.